# How to show an extra option(beside Like,Share,Comment) while sharing with Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, social-framework

I am beginner in iOS, i want to implement a new option beside Like,Comment and Share while sharing with Facebook in iOS. This option is available in other application. Please find the attached screenshot and i marked the required implementation in red box.

[image]

Comment: Please help me, is it possible in ios?Which is worked out in Android.